# How to remove multiple children in one call - Realtime Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I wan to delete multiple children with known key. I searched all the related posts but it doesn't seem to work. It shows red bracket.

**Below is my code which i refer from other posts:**

```
var updates = { } 

for(i in removedProductVariationIdList){
    updates["user/$i"] = null
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Firebase Structure** (I want to remove 3, 4 under Product_Variation for example, which i know the key)
:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support template literals with the `$i` notation in regular strings, as far as I know. The simplest way to build a map with the null values:

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
for(i in removedProductVariationIdList){
    updates.put("user"+i, null);
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Transactions of Add, Delete on Multiple Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689285/firebase-transactions-of-add-delete-on-multiple-nodes/45695483#45695483)

Comment: I'm using Kotlin, my bad not specifying it in question.

Comment: I've tried `val updates = hashMapOf<String, Object?>()
        for (i in removedProductVariationIdList){
            updates.put("/$i", null)
        }
        productVariationRef.updateChildren(updates)`. But it underlines `update` in `.updateChildren()`, saying `expected <String,Any>, but found <String, Object>

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `values` as a map.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
```

Comment: Then how do i add into `map` which path i want to set to `null`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be ```MutableMap``` instead of ```Map```. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

With the help from Frank's reference link and danartillaga answers, below is my code in `Kotlin` which works:

```
val productVariationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Product_Variation")

val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any?>()
for (i in removedProductVariationIdList){
   updates.put("/$i", null)
}
productVariationRef.updateChildren(updates)
```

**Firebase Structure** - It will delete all the key (e.g. 3, 4, 5, 8) stored in `removedProductVariationIdList` together with its children, whole branch dissapears, which is exactly what i want :

[image]